# Javascript - Display Default Table on Load

Tags: javascript, woocommerce

I have this JS which i will paste below.

What this basically does, is display a pricing table depending on the variation you have selected. So the table is only shown when selecting your options.So when a user lands on a product page, there is now table until they select the variations.

What i would like to do, is display any table of the variations when landing on the page but still have the ability to change the table as the users selects the options.

What id did was change

```
jQuery('.rp_wcdpd_pricing_table_variation').hide();
```

to

```
jQuery('.rp_wcdpd_pricing_table_variation').show();
```

But then this shows all the variation tables instead of just 1.

Original code:

```
    /**
     * VARIABLE PRODUCT PRICING TABLE
     */
    function rp_wcdpd_switch_variable_pricing_tables(element_id) {
        jQuery('.rp_wcdpd_pricing_table_variation').hide();
        jQuery(element_id).show();
    }

    if (jQuery('.rp_wcdpd_pricing_table_variation').length) {
        jQuery('input:hidden[name="variation_id"]').each(function() {
            rp_wcdpd_switch_variable_pricing_tables('#rp_wcdpd_pricing_table_variation_' + jQuery(this).val());

            jQuery(this).change(function() {
                rp_wcdpd_switch_variable_pricing_tables('#rp_wcdpd_pricing_table_variation_' + jQuery(this).val());
            });
        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask to jquery to show all elements with this class. 
Use `jQuery('.rp_wcdpd_pricing_table_variation').first().show();`  to show only the first table

Comment: Thank you L.Dia, that did work. Now only issue is that as i select the variations, it keeps adding them right under the default one... So as i select a variation, it adds under the other. So instead of replacing the default one, it adds it under and keeps doing that as i select.

Comment: In your select listener keep `jQuery('.rp_wcdpd_pricing_table_variation').hide();` in any case you hide all the tables and then show the one with the id you clicked on.

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick! Finally question...any way to hide the first / default table completely once i have selected and option?

Comment: Where do you put the line that show the first table ?

Comment: function rp_wcdpd_switch_variable_pricing_tables(element_id) {
        jQuery('.rp_wcdpd_pricing_table_variation').hide();
  jQuery('.rp_wcdpd_pricing_table_variation').first().show();
        jQuery(element_id).show();
    }

Comment: remove it from the function and place it outside :)

Comment: Thank you:-) Still struggling mmmm can you possibly paste an example for me?

Comment: Just place it under your 'if' condition and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one table with the class `rp_wcdpd_pricing_table_variation` then it will definitely show them all.

If you want to only show one then you have to get the first one from the array

`$('.rp_wcdpd_pricing_table_variation')` This returns an array containing all the elements that have this class.

To get the first one you need to add `.first()` so it would be `$('.rp_wcdpd_pricing_table_variation').first().show()`

Comment: Thank you, that did work. Now only issue is that as i select the variations, it keeps adding them right under the default one... So as i select a variation, it adds under the other. So instead of replacing the default one, it adds it under and keeps doing that as i select.